# What is the meaning of "although the literature maintains that it’s a noble thing"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I do not understand what "although the literature maintains that it’s a noble thing" really means.

Here is the full sentence: Dealing with unrequited love is remarkably unpleasant, and although the literature maintains that it’s a noble thing, there is no escaping the fact that it is painful.

Comment: This is just speculation, but perhaps you're having trouble with the meaning of *maintain* as it is used in this sentence. The meaning in this context is the fourth one listed [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maintain).

Answer (score 1):

**The literature** refers here to the collected body of all literature written by humanity.

To **maintain** in this sense means to assert something, to say that something is the case.